# Cannot create an Array of ArrayList<Object> elements, passing list of Objects as a parameter

Tags: java

This is my code and it works:

```
Value[] params2 = {val};
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("package." + className);
Method[] thisMethod = clazz.getMethods();
thisMethod[0].invoke(clazz.newInstance(), new Object[]{params2});
```

However when I try to send list of 'val' objects as a parameter,

```
List<Value>[] params2 = {valList};
```

I get:
'Cannot create a generic array of List error'

How can I pass list of val objects as a paramter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<Value>[]` means array where members of this array are lists. Ie. `{new ArrayList<Value>()}` is the instance. If your methods takes as an argument a list, this is the way. Otherwise you should convert the list of params to array, because that is how the Java reflection API was designed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array of arguments to invoke a method reflectively, not a `List` of arguments.  If you have a `List`, use its `toArray()` method.